# How to correct the fields in this python IIS parser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, iis

I created a script that allows me to convert IIS logs from txt -> csv. The issue is that the date does not populate only the time, and the fields are shifted over an extra cell to the right.

```
import os
import re
import csv

# Define the directory where the IIS log files are stored
log_directory = "C:/IISLogs"

# Define a regular expression pattern to match the log files
log_file_pattern = re.compile(r'.+\.log$')

# Define the output directory where the CSV files will be stored
output_directory = "C:/IISLogs/CSV"

# Ask the user to specify an output directory
new_output_directory = input("Enter the path to the output directory (or leave blank to use default): ")
if new_output_directory != "":
    output_directory = new_output_directory

# Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(output_directory):
    os.makedirs(output_directory)

# Loop through all the files in the directory and subdirectories
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(log_directory):
    for filename in files:
        # Check if the file is an IIS log file
        if log_file_pattern.match(filename):
            # Define the full path to the log file
            log_file_path = os.path.join(subdir, filename)

            # Open the log file for reading
            with open(log_file_path, 'r') as log_file:
                # Define the CSV output file path
                output_file_path = os.path.join(output_directory, os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".csv")

                # Open the CSV output file for writing
                with open(output_file_path, 'w', newline='') as output_file:
                    csv_writer = csv.writer(output_file)

                    # Loop through each line in the log file
                    for line in log_file:
                        # Split the line into fields
                        fields = line.split()

                        # Write the fields to the CSV file
                        csv_writer.writerow(fields)
```

How can I remove the field indicator, all my attempts to do so have failed also is there a way to easily connect the date and the time?

Comment: Most of the code you have posted is irrelevant to your problem. See how to create a [mcve] and then [edit] the question. E.g. what are the values of `line` and `fields`, what do you get when you call `writerow(fields)`, and what did you expect. This is enough.

Comment: I used some of your code to convert the file format, and I found that the time and date you mentioned are saved correctly, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIctk.png), and [its result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR7JA.png). If possible, please provide possible details.